# Parsing JSON using Javascript. JSON from Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, laravel

I am using laravel to query google's search api. Here is the code that does that:

```
Route::get('google/(:any)', function($query)
{
    $uri = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=".$query;
    $response = Httpful::get($uri)->send();
    $r = json_decode($response); 
    return Response::json($r);
});
```

This can be accessed by http://example.com/w/google/queryhere

I am also trying to make more than one requests in javascript and parsing the json.

```
$.when( $.ajax(google), $.ajax(bing), $.ajax(yahoo)).then(function(resp1, resp2, resp3)
{ 
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(resp1);
});
```

However, I am getting an unexpected syntax token when using the parseJSON method. I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: can you provide the json response you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parses JSON responses on itself as it detects the content type - you don't need to do that manually.

Second, [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) applied on promises that resolve with multiple arguments is a bit obscure. Usually, a callback on an ajax deferred has 3 arguments: `data, textStatus, jqXHR`. Yet, the combined promise will resolve with them as an array (one array per deferred).

So change it to

```
$.when( $.ajax(google), $.ajax(bing), $.ajax(yahoo)).then(function(resp1, resp2, resp3){ 
    var obj = resp1[0];
});
```